# How can I change location of login dialog in GDM?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, login, customization

How can I change location of login panel on **Ubuntu 10.10** start up page, where entering password. I want to move it down and now it is in center of screen

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change stuff at your login screen, I find it easiest to do like this:

Log out

Press ctrl+alt+F1

log in with your username and password

Run the following commands

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo -u gdm gnome-terminal
```

Press ctrl+alt+F8

Use the terminal there. For example gnome-appearance-properties.

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the screen where you enter your user name and password to login to the system on startup (gdm) then there is no permanent way to change this *(technically there is a way to change it, but only temporarily; it would require for you to change the theme)*

*follow this at your own risk!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*

`alt+f2>gksu -u gdm gnome-appearance-properties>click on customise>change your windows border theme.`

*the next time you log in, you **should** be able to move the login panel, but it will reset every time you log in*